# How to 'tilt' a regression line

Tags: regression

I would like to know how I would go about essentially tilting a regression line. Say I have a regression line with a slope of exactly 1. I would like to instead, tilt the entire regression line clockwise so that it maintains the same distribution, but looks more like a flat line with no slope.

Comment: What does "maintains the same distribution" mean? What is this "tilting" intended to represent?  What relationship is the resulting line supposed to have with the original data (or bivariate distribution) with which the regression was performed?

Comment: Can *tilting the regression line* be formulated as *shrinking the regression coefficient towards zero*? Then you could think about shrinkage methods like LASSO or ridge regression. However, I am not sure how that would affect the distribution of errors.

Comment: @RichardHardy: weal, for one it will make the sum of squared errors larger;)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean to change the data so it has a regression line that's close to flat?

If so, just subtract some multiple of the predictor (IV, x-variable) from each data point. The slope changes by that multiple. e.g. if you say $y^*=y-2x$ then the slope of a regression of $y^*$ on $x$ will be 2 smaller than a regression of the original $y$ on $x$.

If you want it exactly flat, just take the residuals from the least squares fit as your 'tilted' $y$.